# Unable to inspect the WPF Application?

Tags: winappdriver

Using 'Windows Kits' 'Inspect.exe' I am trying to inspect the WPF application but I am unable to find the controls, I am getting message like:
"Cannot get object from point:
[Error: FromPoint: hr=0x80070005 - Access is denied.]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using VisualUIAVerifyNative.exe. I am using that for WPF application. Personally I feel, it is much convenient than Inspect.exe

Comment: Thanks Bharat for reply.